# why doesn't work my code 'send_keys' in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Gjz.png)

"error in ".send_keys("black_pink")"
what's the problem??

I changed my code  "driver = webdriver.Chrome()" to "driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)" but nothing changed

Comment: The error of the code is present in the stacktrace itself (the image that you provided). Your code is not working due to `NoSuchElementException`. In such a case you would want to revisit the locators that you've added (i.e. `#search_btn` and `input_text`.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: //*[@name='q'] Is a simple xpath for the google website for the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Pls Provide Some code Snippet so i can slove your problem but for now I am providing some code snippet that i use for AI project i hope it help you.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys   import  Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by  import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def selenium_config():
    options = Options()
  
    driver_manager = ChromeDriverManager() #selenium and webdriver config
    chrome_service = Service(driver_manager.install())                       
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
    return driver


driver = selenium_config()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
while True:
            audiotext = input("Enter: ")
            if "search" in audiotext:
                audiotext = audiotext.replace("search", "")
                element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
                element.clear()
                element.send_keys(audiotext)
                element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```